# Would we see aliens on Europa?

Tags: science-based, solar-system, outer-solar-system

If aliens were to bring a space ship to the solar system, and put it in orbit around a Jupiter moon, and then begin colonising the surface of the planet, what would we be able to see from using current day technology?

Presuming the best case scenario, i.e. we are at a close orbit with Jupiter, etc.

How big would their ship need to be to be visible to us? Are there any 'major' telescopes regularly pointed at Jupiter, or would it be more likely picked up by someone with a (big) telescope in their backyard?
How long would it take us to develop / deploy a probe to investigate (and how long to get there)?

ETA...

The main question here is about visibility. With today's technology, what would we see?

Comment: Too many questions in a single post. Please pick one

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke had a pretty good take on those things already in 2001: A Space Odyssey and the sequel.  Europa was even the planet with life on it.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica Those all seem to be the same questions asked slightly differently.

Comment: @JohnO, how is "can we see X around Europa?" be the same as "how long to develop something capable of seeing X around Europa?"

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The hope for the answer would be something like 'with modern telescopes, we'd only be able to see x, in order to see better we would need to send something there, though that would take y/z to achieve' - it is all based on the title ''would we see aliens on Europa'

Comment: Arthur C. Clarke wrote almost that exact story: [Jupiter Five (1953)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Five), so be sure to read it and insert a few homages in your creation.

Comment: What about seeing in infrared? If aliens have large activities on the planet that may mean heat produced as a consequence. We may be able to pick that up with IR telescopes but it would need to be pretty big, like a major volcanic eruption.

Comment: We may be able to pick up radio signals too depending on the technology they may be using. But that may not be considered 'seeing'.

Answer (score 9):

**Probes!**

Yeh, Fish suggested this in the comments.  But here is a sweet image!

[image: europa]

> This close-up view of the icy surface of Europa, a moon of Jupiter,
> was obtained on Dec. 20, 1996, by the Solid State Imaging system on
> board the Galileo spacecraft during its fourth orbit around Jupiter.
> The view is about 7 miles by 10 miles (11 kilometers by 16 kilometers)
> and has a resolution of 28 yards (26 meters). The Sun illuminates the
> scene from the east (right).

https://europa.nasa.gov/resources/110/close-up-of-europas-surface/

Check out the crater that cleared off the cracks next to it.  The link explains what happened there - stuff melted and flooded!  26 meters is good enough resolution to make out an average sized middle school and you could easily see a golf course.

In any case - there has been a pretty steady presence of one probe or another out Jupiter way.   [A dedicated Europa mission](https://europa.nasa.gov/mission/about/) is going to happen sometime this decade.   [Juno](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/juno/main/index.html) is out there now and it has taken some incidental pictures of Europa.  A Michael Crichton type fiction would have the Earth folks make use of resources like Juno already on the scene to get a better look at what was going on with Europa.

Comment: Mind you, the surface of Europa (as shown in your image) is a VERY complex texture and any artificial adding/changing thereof might not be very obvious at all. One could superimpose the entire US Interstate highway system on Europa, and it would get lost to casual observation unless you do detailed before/after imagery comparisons.

Comment: @PcMan what if Europa's surface *is* the US interstate highway station? (united states of aliens)

Comment: @user253751 I'd think if anything, it'd be the highway system of *Europe*, all things considered.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - because of how the layout is organized?

Comment: @Willk No, just because Europa/Europe.  (I don't know how closely it resembles any Earth highway system, just making a joke.)

Answer (score 9):

**Without offering any proof for my assertions...**

1. Electromagnetic emissions that don't belong. Should your aliens use EM transmissions (optical or radiometric), then it's possible to detect them here on Earth using current tech. After all, we're still detecting both Voyagers, and they're a honking lot further away than Europa.
2. Heat. This one is a little less believable because it would depend on the resolution of thermal detectors... but unless your aliens are using some cool tech (every possible pun intended), the exhaust from their ship(s) could be detectable.
3. Shadows. A number of previous answers have suggested that our cameras simply aren't good enough to detect a ship of reasonable size. However, that doesn't mean that the ship orbiting Europa (and, therefore, Jupiter) at an opportune angle to the Sun wouldn't cast a long shadow that could be detected and shouldn't be there. You'd have to be watching at just the right moment for something like this, but it's possible. (Consider this in real time. A shadow suddenly appears on the surface of one of the two spheres, momentarily grows longer, then vanishes... talk about cool ju ju for your story.)
4. Radiation. Rather than assuming a combustion-style engine as I did in #2, let's assume a nuclear-style engine. Those things burp radiation all over the place.
5. And with a [massive caveat](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/193036/40609), depending on what the surface of the ship is like, and if the angles are once again opportune, the flash of light off the ship could be detected. (I admit that this is a specialized version of #1, but #1 was meant to convey communications tech, not happenstantial "oh, crap, we didn't think about painting the darn ship!" problems.)
6. Finally, and this one is way out into left field, consider the possibility of an exotic drive like the Albecurrie drive. We're warping space, donchaknow... and I wonder if warping space means you're warping gravity right along with it. It might be that if the navigator brought the ship out of warp just a little too late, the result would be a small but detectable shift in the orbit of Europa. Gravity, it's a harsh mistress....

Comment: I like no. 1 because SETI would mostly pick up an incoming ship if it uses the [21 cm hydrogen line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line).

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you for answering a lot of questions I didn't ask, but definitely appreciate having answered!

Comment: My knowledge about this topic is rather popular-sciencey, but wouldn't 6 cause a ripple in gravitational fields that could be detected with LIGO? We may not know immediately where did it come from, but we would be alarmed nevertheless.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen considering that LIGO can just barely detect black holes spinning around each other a hundred times a second, I wouldn't count on it. Mind you, the distance is also a lot shorter...

Comment: The Voyager probes are deliberately sending focused signals directly at us.  If they were just sending non-directional signals any old place (as you might expect from Europa-ian aliens), it'd likely be too weak to reach us.  (What *would* you call aliens from Europa anyhow?  Europeans seems the obvious choice, but that word is already taken...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman you're point is well taken, but let's add that the probes were designed with, for lack of a better term, minimalist solutions in mind. There's only so much power that could be spared for comms. This problem wouldn't exist with a big unobtanium-powered space ship. In other words, for every reason someone comes up with justifying why Voyager isn't a spot-on example, I can probably come up with a suspension-of-disbelief rebuttal. (You can see why I prefixed my answer with a disclaimer, though...  )

Answer (score 7):

This is what Hubble can see from Europa, as published by [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-s-hubble-spots-possible-water-plumes-erupting-on-jupiters-moon-europa)

[image]

> This composite image shows suspected plumes of water vapor erupting at the 7 o’clock position off the limb of Jupiter’s moon Europa. The plumes, photographed by NASA’s Hubble’s Space Telescope Imaging Spectrograph, were seen in silhouette as the moon passed in front of Jupiter. Hubble’s ultraviolet sensitivity allowed for the features -- rising over 100 miles (160 kilometers) above Europa’s icy surface -- to be discerned. The water is believed to come from a subsurface ocean on Europa. The Hubble data were taken on January 26, 2014. The image of Europa, superimposed on the Hubble data, is assembled from data from the Galileo and Voyager missions.

The plume at the bottom of the planet is about 8 pixels in height. Taking for good that its height is 160 km, it means that a single pixel resolves about 20 km.

This means that anything smaller than 20 km won't be resolvable: we would just see it as a single pixel.

Forget about reaching those resolutions with a backyard telescope.

Comment: If we have a probe passing by (such as Galileo, Voyager, or Juno), we can get an image like the superimposed Europa or better, so we might see smaller structures. Without such a probe, yeah, this is our current best.

Comment: So it would need to be a really, really big ship then! - thank you :)

Comment: The Juno probe is currently orbiting Jupiter. While its primary task is to observe Jupiter itself, it will make several close passes to the moons, to alter its orbit. Notably both Ganymede and Europa. So yes, we do currently have eyes on site there, although it is not nearly optimized for ground surface surveys it might well detect something. A dedicated Europa probe would be the best, of  course, but the Europa Clipper is only scheduled for launch in 2024, arrival in april 2030.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding, "*... would it be more likely picked up by someone with a (big) telescope in their back yard?*", the Hubble Space Telescope is among the highest resolution telescopes in existence.  According to https://hubblesite.org/contents/media/images/2009/12/2508-Image.html, "*Hubble can see details as small as 190 miles (300 km) across on Saturn.*" from Earth using its Wide Field Planetary Camera 2 ([EDIT] a different instrument than the one used in the other answer), so your hypothetical spacecraft would need to be at least that large and distinguishable from the background to be detected even by Hubble.  A backyard telescope has no hope of detecting such a spacecraft, short of it being extraordinarily luminous.

If you want to do estimates, this site discusses the details of Hubble's resolution and limitations: https://illuminateduniverse.org/2019/04/11/angular-resolution-and-what-hubble-cant-see/

Comment: That's a useful read! - thank you

Answer (score 3):

If your aliens are technological civilization, they will probably use radio-frequency communications. Or their machinery will emit radio frequency electromagnetic waves we could detect.
I think we will manage to intercept their communications, first -  accidentaly ("what is this strange interferences?"), than intentionally ("we have tuned radio-telescopes and send probe to Europa to investigate strange radio interferences coming from it").
Than probe will find something unusual on orbit and surface of Europe...

Comment: Europa is a close moon of Jupiter. And that planet is the greatest source of radio frequency noise in the whole solar system, after the Sun itself. Small signals could get lost in the noise *easily*. Also: as we develop higher tech, our radio transmissions become less energetic, and more resemble pure noise. It is reasonable to extrapolate this trend for superadvanced aliens, too.

Comment: The assumption that advanced technology implies detectable radio emissions is not valid. A civilization might pass through a short period of using high power, narrow band radios, as humans have done, but it is more likely that an ultra-wideband, low power technology would be used. Humans, just weren't smart enough go from the early on/off spark-gap transmissions, to more effective spread-spectrum radios. We had a tendency to think that more power output was better than more sensitive receivers. We just didn't have the math. Had Shannon been born 30 years earlier, the outcome might be different

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is it depends if the aliens want to be seen.

If they want to be seen they could send out radio messages, generate unusual heat or magnetic effects and paint the ship bright orange among other possibilities.

If they don't want to be seen then there would be little chance of finding them as things stand. They could use some fairly simple camouflage to blend into the background making them virtually invisible. They could also maintain radio silence and modify the heat signature to look like something else like a diffuse plume from a crack in the crust.

If they simply don't care then its hard to say as they might or might not give themselves away by various means. All other things being equal I think we would be very lucky indeed to spot them unless the colonization process was already very advanced and covered a substantial area.

Answer (score 0):

#### Rocket engines are bright.

Simply put, any rocket engine capable of taking off and landing on the surface of Europa will be quite bright, whether it's a chemical rocket or some form of nuclear rocket. It's got a surface gravity of about .134 Gs, so you'd need a rocket with a thrust-to-mass ratio of at least that much in order to land there.

However, given that this is interplanetary or interstellar flight, you're going to need to burn your rocket to decelerate, and that drive plume will be extremely visible. The luminosity of the rocket would depend on how large the rocket is, how fast it's going, and its acceleration, but it's entirely possible that a torch ship pulling a 1g acceleration would become visible to the naked eye, and amateur astronomers might notice it as a new "star" - a new "star" that is moving, no less!

Something like an Alcubierre drive might not create such luminous plumes, but if you're flying FTL, you won't be able to see where you're going, so it's entirely possible that it won't show up immediately in Jupiter orbit, and it'll need to perform rocket burns for interplanetary flight to get there. It's also entirely possible that we might see such a rocket approaching by observing the distortions in the light of other stars that it would produce, though that might require a bit of luck in pointing a telescope at an area where it happened to by flying past.

Comment: "a torch ship pulling a 1g acceleration would become visible to the naked eye".. it would need to be about as bright as a 200kiloton nuke, per second, to be visible from Earth using human eyes. As a 7th magnitude at-the-utter-edge-of-visibility light. Which will be drowned by the light of Jupiter.

Comment: How bright? What would the resulting magnitude be (that would set the limit for how small the telescope could be. And also if it could actually be observed with the moon's own bright light - you will not know if a 13th magnitude star is there if very close to a 6th magnitude by observing the combined light - even observing differences over time would require a 0.3% accuracy)?

Comment: @PcMan "it would need to be about as bright as a 200kiloton nuke, per second, to be visible from Earth using human eyes" Sounds about right, if it's a big enough ship and it's powered by a nuclear salt water rocket or some sort of fusion torch. The designs for Project Orion involved a 6000 ton rocket that used nuclear pulse devices about a tenth of that yield for space flight, IIRC. Even a much smaller rocket would be glaringly obvious to telescopes, however. Stealth in space isn't realistically possible once you fire off your engines.

Comment: Interstellar drives must be highly efficient. To achieve high efficiency, the engine exhaust plume should be very cold and high velocity, therefore defuse and far less detectable than most of our current chemical rockets. Hot ejecta, wastes energy on lateral motion of atoms/molecules. The engine would pretty much have to be pointed straight at you, to see anything at all. Likely undetectable. Even our own current landers retro rockets have invisible plumes, in the absence of an atmosphere to react with.

Comment: @jwdonahue http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacewardetect.php#nostealth

Comment: @nick012000, rocket engines do not have to be bright to be powerful, and you don't actually need or even want high thrust. For deep-space, you must have efficiency, or you're just not going to get very far, very fast. My comment had nothing to do with whether there can be stealth in space, my comment had to do with your assumption that all spaceships are "torch ships", which simply isn't the case. Just view the images of the sky crane from our recent Mars landing. Zero visible plume and the camera was looking right up the nozzle.

Comment: @jwdonahue There's a significant difference between a tiny unmanned probe and an interstellar colonisation ship, and that difference means that different types of engines would be optimal; you will never go interstellar with a chemical rocket. Besides, even if you were using a highly efficient rocket engine, you'd still be visible; that page I just linked to has an equation for determining how far away a rocket can be detected during thrust.

Comment: Our current best tech for interstellar travel, are cold ion drives. Even the chemical lander thrusters, if scaled up, would still not emit much, if any visible lite. The key there, is the endothermic reaction that makes them so efficient, while still having high thrust. The matter stream is cold. You'd have detect a very thin and easily scattered trail of matter, emanating from the ship, by indirect means.

Comment: @jwdonahue From the link I gave: "A Russian Oscar submarine has a mass of about 15,000 metric tons. Say it was accelerating at a tiny one-tenth of a g (As = 0.1). A chemical rocket has an Isp of around 450 seconds, an ion drive has 21,000 seconds, and a steady-state plasma has about 30,000 seconds.

This means the maximum detection range of the chemical Oscar is about 1.2 billion kilometers (7.7 AU), and both the ion Oscar and the steady-state plasma Oscar is 25 billion km (167.4 AU). For purposes of comparison the distance between the Sun and Pluto is about 40 AU."

Comment: @nick012000, I don't think temperature is necessarily proportional to Isp. Are you saying that ion drives have to run hot? I really doubt that is the case. Might be true of the drives in use today, but I can imagine more than one kind of cold mass driver with high Ips. I am not a physicist, but I can't think of any reason why ions have to be hot. Now other EM leakage from the drive systems is certainly possible and may be detectible in some cases. That said, a true colony size ship is probably going to use a fusion drive, and that could be very bright indeed.

Comment: Since helium remains liquid down to 0K and a mist of it could fairly easily be ionized, you'd have a few K tolerance to work with, before you had to worry about exceeding the temperature of the CMB. If your only concern was whether your destination could see you coming, then you could probably arrange a flight trajectory that gave a few tens of K additional tolerance. I don't see why a long enough EM accelerator couldn't achieve very high Ips and control exit temperature within the required tolerance.

Comment: @jwdonahue Have you read the link I gave? Stealth in space is basically impossible.

Comment: Well then, if the link says so, it must be so.

Comment: @jwdonahue Atomic Rockets is a website that discusses actual rocket science, with references to relevant texts. You would be able to tell that if you had actually read the page I had linked to.

Comment: I skimmed it and wasn't impressed. Take finding the 20W emissions from Voyager 1 as an example. If you didn't know what to look for and where to look for it, it wouldn't stand out. The fact is, all of our current stealth aircraft, can be seen in plain view and if you know what to look for and where it is, you'll see it. That doesn't mean they aren't stealthy. They are stealthy, because they don't leap out you screaming "hear I am" the way a "torch ship" would. I am just saying, it's not necessarily the case that such a ship would be all that bright. Especially if they didn't want to be noticed

Comment: I wonder what percentage of the theoretically resolvable pixels of the nearby galaxy, using current best technology, actually have such sensors pointed at them? I'll bet it's very low. Probably on the order of <1 percent at most, and most of those sensor don't operate at anywhere near the theoretical limits of current technology. Stealth doesn't require invisibility, it only requires that the probability of detection is low. When a Marine sneaks up on the enemy, they just have to be careful the enemy isn't looking their direction.

Comment: @nick012000 All you say is true, but utterly out of context. According to your *"Realictic* (sic) *space battles / ships"* source, this is the *maximum* distance a rocket can be detected, with the stated telescope. If the exhaust is pointed directly at the observer. "Realictic"ally, i do not find this argument compelling.